# Perf stat counts context-switches in what way?

Tags: linux, performance, scheduling, perf, infiniband

`perf stat` displays some interesting statistics that can be gathered from examining hardware and software counters.
In my research, I couldn't find any reliable information about what counts as a context-switch in `perf stat`. In spite of my efforts, I was unable to understand the kernel code in its entirety.
Suppose my InfiniBand network application calls a blocking `read` system call in the event mode  2000 times and `perf stat` counts 1,241 context switches. The context-switches refer to either the schedule-in process or the schedule-out process, or both?

The `__schedule()` function (`kernel/sched/core.c`) increments the `switch_count` counter whenever `prev != next`.
It seems that `perf stats`' context-switches include involuntary switches as well as voluntary switches.

It seems to me that only deschedule events are counted if the current context runs the schedule code and increases the `nvcsw` and `nivcsw` counters in the `task_struct`.

output from `perf stat -- my_application`:

```
         1,241      context-switches
```

Meanwhile, if I only count the `sched:sched_switch` event the output is close to the expected number.

output from `perf stat -e sched:sched_switch -- my_application`:

```
         2,168      sched:sched_switch
```

Is there a difference between `context-switches` and the `sched_switch`- event?

Comment: Related: [Why does \`perf stat\` show 0 context switches?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439260) for a microbenchmark that generates blocking reads without other load.  Also maybe  [Understanding Linux Perf sched-switch and context-switches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259710) / [How does "perf sched record" count context switches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45969930) (involuntary vs. all).  https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html has some examples of tracing when context-switches happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only get a count for `context-switches` if a different task actually runs on a core that was running one of your threads.  A `read()` that blocks, but resumes before any user-space code from any other task runs on the core, probably won't count.

Just entering the kernel at all for a system-call clearly doesn't count; `perf stat ls` only counts one context-switch in a largish directory for me, or zero if I `ls` a smaller directory like `/`.  I get much higher counts, like `711` for a recursive `ls` of a directory that I hadn't accessed recently, on a magnetic HDD.  So it spent significant time waiting for I/O, and maybe running bottom-half interrupt handlers.

The fact that the count can be odd means it's not counting both deschedule and re-schedule separately; since I'm looking at counts for a single-threaded process that eventually exited, if it was counting both the count would have to be even.

I expect the counting is done when `schedule()` decides that `current` should change to point to a new task that isn't this one.  (`current` is the Linux kernel's per-core variable that points to the `task_struct` of the current task, e.g. a user-space thread.)  So every time that happens to a thread that's part of your process, you get 1 count.

Indeed, the OP helpfully tracked down the source code; it's in `__schedule` in `kernel/sched/core.c`.  For example [in Linux 6.1](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L6492)

```c
static void __sched notrace __schedule(unsigned int sched_mode)
{
    struct task_struct *prev, *next;
    unsigned long *switch_count;
    // and some other declarations I omitted
      ...
      cpu = smp_processor_id();
      rq = cpu_rq(cpu);   // stands for run queue
    prev = rq->curr;
      ...
    switch_count = &prev->nivcsw;        // either Num InVoluntary CSWs I think
      ...
    if (!(sched_mode & SM_MASK_PREEMPT) && prev_state) {
        ...
        switch_count = &prev->nvcsw;     // or     Num Voluntary CSWs
    }

    next = pick_next_task(rq, prev, &rf);
      ...
    if (likely(prev != next)) {
        ...
        ++*switch_count;        //// INCREMENT THE SELECTED COUNTER
        ...
        trace_sched_switch(sched_mode & SM_MASK_PREEMPT, prev, next, prev_state);

        // then make some function calls to actually do the context switch 
        ...
    }
```

I would guess the `context-switches` perf event sums both involuntary and voluntary switches away from a thread.  (Assuming that's what `nv` and `niv` stand for.)

Comment: The __schedule() function (sched/core.c) increments the switch_count
counter whenever prev != next. 
It seems that perf stats include involuntary switches as well as voluntary switches.

Comment: @Bahamas: I'd certainly hope it would count pre-emptions, not just intentional yields or blocking I/O!  The name `context-switches` would be highly misleading otherwise.

Comment: It seems to me that only deschedule events are counted if the current context runs the schedule code and increases the nvcsw and nivcsw counters in the task_struct.

Comment: @Bahamas: Correct, counting the number of times we switch *away* from a thread makes sense.  It increases one *or* the other of `nivcount` or `nvcount`, after picking which to point to with a default and an `if`.  Involuntary or voluntary I guess?  I assume the context switch perf event sums both.